# Searching between two datetimepicker in access database

Tags: c#, ms-access

Code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {

           OleDbDataAdapter dbc = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT ReceiptID,ID,Name,Paid,Due FROM lastpays where [Dateofpayment] >= "+ dateTimePicker1.Value.Date + " AND [Dateofpayment] < " + dateTimePicker2.Value.Date + "", con);

            DataTable data = new DataTable();
            dbc.Fill(data);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
        }
```

Error:

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Syntax error (missing operator) in
>   query expression '[Dateofpayment] >= 11-01-2020 12:00:00 AM AND
>   [Dateofpayment] < 11-01-2020 12:00:00 AM'.'

Comment: Honestly? Use parameters.

Comment: why using parameter is required!

Comment: @UtsabOjha Two main reasons: 1) SQL Injection and 2) To prevent issues relating to serializing values to text.

Comment: @Dai Actually I have no concern about SQL injection as it is a test software.Btw thanks for the second reason.

Comment: @UtsabOjha **You cannot have no concern about SQL injection**. Even if you have no malicious users, things like typing an apostrophe in a textbox (for someone's name) or a double-dash `--` inside a numeric text input can cause SQL injection which will, at best, cause incorrect query results, and at worst: delete or corrupt all of your data. **ALWAYS USE PARAMETERS!**

Comment: @Dai Thank you for your suggestions and always use parameters 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- MS Access (JET Red) requires date literals in SQL to be in the form `#MM/dd/yyyy#`.
- Your code however inserts the default string representation of a `DateTime` value using `CurrentCulture`, without using any delimiters.

  - Because you're directly concatenating `String` values with `DateTime` values, which invokes `DateTime.ToString()` which is `CurrentCulture`-sensitive.
- Use parameters to avoid this issue entirely, and to prevent SQL injection.
- Also, you're using the same `dateTimePicker` instance for both values - I think you mean to use `dateTimePicker1` and `dateTimePicker2` - though you should rename them to `minDatePicker` and `maxDatePicker` to be clear what their purpose is.

```
const String sql = @"SELECT ReceiptID,ID,Name,Paid,Due FROM lastpays where [Dateofpayment] >= ? AND [Dateofpayment] < ?";

OleDbCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = sql;

OleDbParameter pFrom = cmd.CreateParameter();
pFrom.OleDbType = OleDbType.Date;
pFrom.Value     = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date;
cmd.Parameters.Add( pFrom );

OleDbParameter pTo = cmd.CreateParameter();
pTo.OleDbType = OleDbType.Date;
pTo.Value     = dateTimePicker2.Value.Date;
cmd.Parameters.Add( pTo );

OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter( selectCommand: cmd );

DataTable data = new DataTable();
da.Fill( data );
dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
```

Comment: Yah, it should be datetimepicker2 .Thanks a lot! it works!

Comment: I think it is worth noting (as it might not be obvious to all users) that the parameters must be added in the same order they appear in the query. OleDb doesn't use the named parameters (directly) but only the order.

Answer (score 0):

Even though parameters are preferred, the questioneer deserves an answer why the code is failing.

The date values must be converted to valid string expressions:

```
OleDbDataAdapter dbc = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT ReceiptID,ID,Name,Paid,Due FROM lastpays where [Dateofpayment] >= #"+ dateTimePicker1.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd") + "# AND [Dateofpayment] < #" + dateTimePicker2.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd") + "#", con);
```